# Filter rows in Pandas using a chained condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an initial csv file that contains certian values that I am interested in, and I would like to read it and to filter it at the same time.

The file has the following structure:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | xx |
| NaN | yy |
| 32 | zz |
| 25 | zz |

What I normally do is read it first and then, apply the filter:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";")
df = df[df['A']==25]
```

I would like to know if it is possible to filter it in a chained way such as the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";")\
.where('A'==25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need remove missing rows use [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) with trick for compare if `A` is same like `A`, because `np.nan != np.nan`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";").query('A==A')
```

Or use [selection by callable](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-callable):

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";").loc[lambda x: x.A.notna()]
```

If need test another values:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";").query('A==25')
```

Or:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";").loc[lambda x: x.A == 25]
```